# How can I handle multiple queries with useInfinityQuery?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I need to be able to call multiple endpoints and automatically keep fetching more data using cursors returned from the BE. Multiple queries handling can be done with `useQueries`, but as soon as data is loaded I need to be able to fetch more chunks using cursors, therefore pointing me to `useInfinityQuery`. But the thing is that it seems that this hook cannot handle multiple queries.

```
 const {
    status,
    data,
    isFetching,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
  } = useInfiniteQuery({
    // here there is only the option to use one query 
    queryKey: ['projects'],
    queryFn: fetchProjects,
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => lastPage.nextCursor,
  })
```

And as we cannot use hooks inside callbacks, we cannot map the queries and make multiple calls with the hook.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "this hook cannot handle multiple queries."?

Comment: Hi @SlavaKnyazev.

Imagine that useQueries can handle multiple queries at the same time with concurrency. I need to useInfiniteQuery with multiple queries as well. I need to call multiple apis at the same time and if some of them return a cursor, I need to fetch the next chunk of data, etc. 

So I need the functionality of useQueries as I will need to call several queries and will need the possibility of handling cursors when more data is needed.